# Quantum event horizon?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, event-horizon, causality

Is there a limit in an event horizon like there is with a blackhole and similarly with a causal quantum event that limits quantum behavior and segregates it form causal classical behaviour at this boundary?

Comment: No, and it's not a good question. All behavior is quantum, just that in most cases if you have macroscopic systems or systems which have interacted with an environment, and have decohered and you have to examine statistically, you can use classical physics or maybe statistical quantum mechanics. It's a numbers game, not a range game, and there is no sharp boundary, it depends on what and how you are measuring. No event horizon makes sense.

Comment: @Bob Bee it may not be a good question but if all behaviour is quantum wouldn't the uncertainty of quantum behaviour extrapolate into the macroscopic world. The random behaviour surely would result into a disorded state in the behaviour we observe from day to day. Now I indulge in what I perceive as ordered behaviour, like this conversation wouldn't the world be a complete chaos if all behaviour was quantum.

Answer (score 0):

A limit to the size of the horizon comes from the equality of the Schwarzschild  radius and the (reduced) Compton wavelength. 
\begin{equation}
\lambda=\frac{\hbar}{m c} \qquad r_s=\frac{2 G m }{c^2}
\end{equation}
When the black hole is so small, quantum fluctuation are important and the horizon is not a well defined concept. Remarkably, equating the two quantities select the minimum possible mass for a well defined black hole: the Planck mass.

\begin{equation}
m_P=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar c}{G}}
\end{equation}

Therefore the minimum length for the horizon is approximately the Planck length.

By the way, many recent quantum gravity approach suggest that at such scale the space-time picture is not a good one anymore, and it should be replaced by something more fundamental.